# Can a 74HC4067 multiplexer be operated with 3.3 V while routing a 5 V signal?

Tags: multiplexer, level-shifting

I have a 3.3 V MCU and I'd like to read 16 different digital 5 V signals with a multiplexer whilst minimizing the amount of level-shifting circuitry I need.

Given that the [74HC4067](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4067.pdf) is an 'analog' multiplexer, I'm assuming that the switching circuitry and the switched signal are isolated from each other.

Taking into account the above, would this hypothetical circuit break anything, and is it the most optimal way to achieve my goal? It seems to work on a test-bench, but I'm not certain how well it would hold up in a production application.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 7, section 9 of the datasheet you linked to, it states that switch input voltage shouldn't fall outside the range GND to Vcc. So, if your Vcc = 3.3V, you won't be able to reliably route 5V signals through those switches.

This is common behaviour for analogue switch ICs with a single positive supply, but devices exist which overcome this limitation by providing pins for multiple supply potentials, effectively widening the switch voltage range, while having digital control inputs which remain TTL or CMOS logic level compatible. Take a look at the [DG451](https://www.mouser.sg/datasheet/2/427/dg451-1766471.pdf) for example.

Alternatively, power the 'HC4067 from +5V, and level translate the digital control lines.

Edit: Or do what @TimWilliams suggested, use a 74HC***T***4067. Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: "level translate" -- or consider the 74HCT4067!

Comment: @TimWilliams It depresses me that this didn't even occur to me. I must be getting old, and rusty.

Comment: @TimWilliams ooooohhhh, clever!

Comment: My backup plan was going to be powering the device w/ 5v and applying a few more voltage translators, but looks like that wouldn't be needed with the TTL chip.

Comment: In your defense, I didn't even notice it in the screenshot, I just thought "huh, I bet there's an HCT of that" and looked it up. Then looked back here. Oh. :)